# How to set a variable by clicking to a link of an auto generated list?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have created a list, generated from a query, that works (no problem here).

What i would like to do is to trigger an event (probably with jQuery, that I know little about) that would set a php variable.

Let's say I have a table with two columns, '`column 1`' and '`column 2`'.
The list has various links with the valor of 'column 2' displayed on them.
I want that, as you click to one of those links, you could set a valor to a variable that equals to the valor in 'column 1' of that row.

This is what I wrote in my **index** page:

```
<div class="example">

    <?php
    $test = new Test();


    $list = $test->getValors($user_id);

    echo '<div id="mylist">';
    foreach ($list as $element) {
        echo '<a href="#">' . $element->COLUMN2 . '</a>';
    }

    echo '</div>';

    $variable = ?;

    ?>
</div>
```

I have nothing in my JavaScript file about it because I don't know how to begin.

Can you give me some directions?

EDIT

I resolved partially, even if this is not complete, i include my new code:
index.php

```
<?php
$test = new Test();


$list = $test->getValors($user_id);

echo '<div id="mylist">';
foreach ($list as $element) {
    echo '<a href="#" class="pointername" id="' . $element->COLUMN1 . '">' . $element->COLUMN2 . '</a>';
}

echo '</div>';

$variable = ?;

?>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("a.pointer").click(function() {
    var variablename = $(this).attr("id");
    $.post("ajax/filewithajax.php", {"postname": variablename});
    $("#content").load("ajax/filewithajax.php");


});

});
```

Comment: You say you have a table, but I don't see any table in your question? What is it you're trying to do? You're question is quite unclear. Do you want to set `$variable` upon a click event? You can't set a PHP variable on a click event (unless you're using ajax, but that makes a complete new request). PHP is rendered on the server, when it's done, it sends the result to the browser, which will show the results and handle the JavaScript.

Comment: That was an example, i would need to do pretty much the same thing with different tables.
So i wanted to be generic with what is a table about, but pretty much they all have a PK column that i would memorize into that variable and a more descrictive column that i use for display on lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a event onclick on `<a>` and call a php function in a other page with jQuery (search about ajax). The php function could return a value that you can use in your main page.

Comment: The problem is that the list of link is auto generated, how can i know which of the auto generated link i clicked on and how i get the value from that column?

Comment: You must make a incrementation on a value in a for loop and gives an id to each link to identify each of them.

Comment: And then i write in my js.
$("a.servicelink").click(function() {
        var select = $(this).attr("id");

Thanks, i did it.